# Multiple pickerviews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to create a simple converter app.

I have two picker views. One to show which unit they have and one picker on the right to show the unit they wish to convert to:

```
Acre                    Acre
Hectare                 Hectare
Square Inch             Square Inch     
Square Meter            Square Meter
Square Kilometer        Square Kilometer
Square Foot             Square Foot
```

I don’t know how to get the picker view on the left to work when you scroll down.

I can only get the first row on the left side to work the way I want (acre -> hectare, acre -> square inch etc).

However when I try hectare -> acre or any other measurement, it doesn’t do the correct measurement.  It does the one for acre.

How do I get the left pickerview to work the way I want to?

I have tried many different ways to get it to work but nothing works so I just deleted it all and went back to the same code.

This is code I have used

```
func pickerView2(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    switch(row) {

    case 0:

      answerField2.text = answerField1.text            

    case 1:

        var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

        var num2:Float = 2.4711

        var answer = num1 / num2

        var display = answer.description

        answerField2.text = display            

    case 2:

        var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

        var num2:Float = 6272600

        var answer = num1 * num2

        var display = answer.description

        answerField2.text = display



    case 3:

        var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

        var num2:Float = 0.00023711

        var answer = num1 / num2

        var display = answer.description

        answerField2.text = display

    case 4:

        var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

        var num2:Float = 247.11

        var answer = num1 / num2

        var display = answer.description

        answerField2.text = display

    case 5:

        var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

        var num2:Float = 43560

        var answer = num1 * num2

        var display = answer.description

        answerField2.text = display            

    default:

        println("not a value")



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a noob so take this advice with a grain of salt.  Look at your first line of code.

```
func pickerView2(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
switch(row) {
```

Your inCompenent component I believe is referring to the first UIViewPicker or the second.  However your switch is looking to switch the row int instead of the component.  Have you tried:

```
switch component{ .....
```